# errors about overload new operator in a template class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I want to overload *new* operator in a template class. But something wrong happends.

In file *test4.h*, I defined a class

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class lei{
 public:
  T me;                                    
  static void* operator new(size_t size);
};
```

*test4.cpp* implement the new operator.

```
#include "test4.h"

template <class T>
void* lei<T>::operator new(size_t size){
  std::cout << size << std::endl;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include "test4.h"

int main(){
  lei<size_t> *pl;
  pl = new lei<size_t>;
}
```

I compile the cpp files to .o file. Everything is OK.
But when I link them to the executable file, error occurs:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `lei<unsigned int>::operator new(unsigned int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but everything is OK, if I don't use *template*.Why that happens? 
So, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the template implementation in the header file also. The implementation needs to be visible to the compiler when it needs to instantiate the template.

This the [C++FAQ 35.12](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12) to learn why this is necessary, and the following entries for ways to fix it.

(Also, your implementation of `operator new` should return something, it should not compile otherwise.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to know why it is invisible to the compiler. Tell me something about the principle, any *answer* or *key word* is welcome.

Comment: Added a link with the explanation. Keywords: "compilation unit" and c++/template should allow you to find out more.

Answer (score 2):

Move the implementation of the operator to the header file, and it should compile.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of your `new` operator needs to be in the header file as well, not the .cpp file.